# Arithmetic Overflow Error if Varchar is over 999, WHY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I discovered a weird issue in my database, I was able to fix it, but I do not understand WHY the error occurred in the first place.  I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

The following code returns an Arithmetic Overflow error:

```
SELECT '1000' / 100.0 FROM table_name
```

```
SELECT '1000.0' / 100.0 FROM table_name
```

Returns Error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

But what is weird is that the following code DOES NOT cause an error:

```
SELECT '100' / 100.0 FROM table_name
```

Returns: 1.000000 for each row.

```
SELECT '999' / 100.0 FROM table_name
```

Returns: 9.990000 for each row.

```
SELECT '100.0' / 100.0 FROM table_name
```

Returns: 1.000000 for each row.

```
SELECT '1000' / 100 FROM table_name
```

Returns: 10 for each row.

I have since fixed the code so that it is using a convert before attempting to do arithmetic, but what bothers me is WHY did the code work without converting numbers less than 1000????  This is really bugging me!

Comment: This is because of the arcane rules about the scale and precision assigned to numeric constants.  The real moral is don't do arithmetic on strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 2 values here:

1. `'1000'` which is a `varchar(4)`
2. `100.0` which is a `decimal(4,1)`

As a result when you perform the expression `'1000' / 100.0` the `varchar`  is implicitly cast to a `decimal` as `decimal` has a higher [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). As, however, the largest value a `decimal(4,1)` can store is `999.9`, then the value `1000` overflows and you get an error.

Comment: This makes sense.  But this brings up a few more questions.  1.  If it is converting the string to a `decimal(4,1)` then why does the error message specify a conversion to `numeric`?  2.  If it was converted to a `decimal(4,1)` then why does `'999'/100.0` return a value of 9.990000?  shouldn't this cause an arithmetic overflow as well?

Comment: `numeric` and `decimal` are synonyms @Alexw .

Comment: And no, `999` is "small" enough to fit in a `decimal(4,1)`, so the conversion is successful.